# How to differentiate between a file path and a url using node?

Tags: node.js, electron

If I have a string which could be either a file or a URL, is there any existing clever method I could use to differentiate them?

For instance:

- /Users/user/Documents/mydoc.txt -> path
- c:\Program Files\myapp\mydoc.doc -> path  (even if mydoc.doc doesn't actully exist on the file system)
- https://mywebsite.com/mydoc.txt -> url
- ftp://myserver.com/myfile.txt -> url

Comment: You can try playing with https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_parse_path and https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_protocol

Comment: or simple string matching or regex